# Custom Fonts React Native Expo - separated fonts file

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am newbie with React Native and Expo and I am just wondering how to deal with custom fonts if I want to load it separated from the App.js? I have all font settings separated in fonts.js file and would love to load custom font there and load it for the whole app.If anyone knows how to tackle this problem please do let me know. Thanks

Here is screenshot of my file structure:
https://dev-to-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/i/00c41lecmtjk2g6ygtvm.png

Comment: https://dev.to/edo_begagic/add-custom-fonts-to-react-native-expo-app-54d ,check this one hope it helps you.

Comment: Tried that already, but doesnt work. As he is adding all required code to app.js and I would like to split it. To keep the files clean and scalable. Not sure if there is a way, but was wondering if someone knows.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem one of the things that worked for me was this:

```js
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';


let [fontlaoded] = useFonts({
'NeulisAltRegular' : require('todo/assets/fonts/NeulisAlt-Regular.ttf'),
'NeulisAltExtraBold' : require('todo/assets/fonts/NeulisAlt-ExtraBold.ttf')

});
```

This allowed me to load them in other files, however They don't load when the app is rebuilt and I have to refresh them.
Another possibility, is to install expo-fonts and to create a file named app.config.js with the following  content:

```js
module.exports = {
  project: {
      ios:{},
      android:{}
  },
  assets:['./assets/fonts/'],
}
```

This somewhat solved the issue for me. Nonetheless as I have tried many solutions without avail (before reaching this point), I can't specify exactly the main element that led to this result.